# Adding to the interface with mongodb data

Tags: python, mongodb, tkinter

[image]

In the picture: I designed an interface with tkinter by pulling data over mongodb. I want it to appear as a mongodb-fed list.

How can I do it.

very uneven like that.

Also, I don't want _id to appear.

**the code I wrote:**

```
import pymongo
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

client = pymongo.MongoClient("secure")
koleksiyon = client["dukkan"]
db = koleksiyon["yaglar"]


master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry("300x300")
 
def buttonCallback():
    uruns  = tk.Toplevel()
    uruns  .geometry("300x300")
    mas    = tk.Label(uruns, text="Urunler listesi")
    veriler = db.find().sort("db")

    for x in veriler:
        urunn = tk.Label(uruns, text=x)

        urunn.pack()
    
    mas.pack()
 
urunler = tk.Button(master, text="Tüm Ürünler", command=buttonCallback)

 
label_1 = tk.Label(master, text="Bolat Aktar ürün yönetim sistemi")
 

label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
urunler.grid(row=1, column=0)

master.mainloop()
```

How can I list regularly?

Comment: [Turkish] Evet ama resimde göründüğü gibi direktmen çıktı olarak değil de Sadece Marka: KRK, Adı: X Çayı, Boyut: 20 mg şeklinde alt alta yazılmasını istiyorum. Yaptığımda direkt geliyor ve json şeklinde geliyor.

Comment: ```python
koleksiyon = client["dukkan"]
db = koleksiyon["yaglar"]
veriler = db.find().sort("db")
print(veriler)
```  
çıktısını ekleyebilir misin konuya kardeşim.

Answer (score 0):

Search for **Python Dictionaries** and **f-Strings**, and you can edit your code like that:

```py
urunn = tk.Label(uruns, text=f"Marka: {x['urunmarkasi']}, "
                             f"Adı: {x['urunadi']}, "
                             f"Boyut: {x['boyut']}, "
                             f"Fiyat: {x['fiyat']}")
```

Comment: the method you said did not happen. looks blank and nothing.